# Should I move a value which I am not using any more?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I would like to know whether it is ever necessary to move values explicitly when I am not inside a move constructor / move assignment. Lets say I have the following situation:

```
struct Node
{
  std::vector<int> items;
};

Node create()
{
  std::vector<int> items;
  items.push_back(2);

  Node n;
  // should I use n.items = std::move(items);
  // instead?
  n.items = items;

  // other code, not using items any more

  return n;
}
```

First of all, is it correct to move an lvalue using `std::move` provided that I don't use the moved value any more in subsequent code?

Secondly, is it faster to move the value explicitly or does the compiler automatically detect that value can be moved?

Comment: a move is better than a copy

Comment: Why not instantiate `n` earlier and save yourself the trouble by pushing directly into `n.items`?

Comment: @user4581301 is right. Can you come up with a noncontrieved example ?

Comment: Well, I don't think it is contrived that much... I recently took a look at the rust language. In that language moving values is an accepted pattern and the compiler actually makes sure that a moved value can't be used any more (as part of their ownership concept)...

Answer (score 1):

You may avoid moving and leave it to initialization of an object and optimization of the compiler:

```
struct Node
{
  std::vector<int> items;
};

Node create()
{
    std::vector<int> items;
    // ...
    return Node{items};
}
```

The usual advice is: Do not apply overhasty manual optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Moving an lvalue is fine so long as you remember that lvalue might not be valid anymore. You can copy something over it and it'll be fine once again, though.

Moving the contents of a vector is generally faster than copying it as it only has to swap the underlying pointer (and a size variable) rather than individually copying each element in the vector. Moving something simple, like an int, is kind of silly, though.

Finally, in your example, it certainly wouldn't hurt to be explicit. `items` is an lvalue, so unless your compiler is clever enough to see items is never used again at all, it probably will use the copy semantics, so being explicit would help.

Comment: Well, the scenario is that the vector contains *more* than one item, the example is really only illustrative:)